# Camera Projection on a Plane

Tags: math, 3d, camera, geometry

Let's say I have a camera looking down on a plane, I need to calculate the position of the four corners of the camera image on the plane.

What I know about the camera is: x, y, height, pitch, heading, roll (all relative to the plane), plus the horizontal and vertical view angles (provided by the camera manufacturer).

Comment: Shouldn't this be in math.stackexchange?

Comment: I'm asking how to solve this programmatically, sorry for being unclear.

Comment: I would imagine the code would be straightforward given a mathematical solution to the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to the solution of the problem is thinking in terms of a camera coordinate system, which is defined by the camera position **c** (which you already know) and three orthonormal vectors, say **u** (right), **v** (up) and **w** (away from camera). These can be computed from pitch, heading and roll (Euler angles); they are the columns of the corresponding rotation matrix (see, e.g., http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node102.html or Wikipedia). The exact formulas depend on your interpretation of these angles (the order in which the transformations are applied).

Using these, you can compute the directions **d** of the four rays **r**(t) = **c** + t **d** that correspond to the image corners as **d** = **w** +/- tan(h/2)**u** +/- tan(v/2)**v** where v and h are the vertical and horizontal view angles.

Finally, you can compute the intersections of these rays with the plane (see, e.g., Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-plane_intersection) to find the corners of the camera image on that plane.

Comment: could you elaborate on what "t" represents in the above? Also, how would would one generate a 2d plane for ray intersection?

Comment: check out [this page](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/ray-tracing-generating-camera-rays) (parameter _t_ explained in the "Defining Rays" section) and [this page](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/minimal-ray-tracer-rendering-simple-shapes/ray-plane-and-ray-disk-intersection) (info on defining plane equations) for a good introduction to raytracing math